# Connection Pool listener

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, database-connection

I am using Oracle Connection Pool UCP in the Java application to connect to Oracle.

My requirement is before the used connection is put back to the pool I want to do a commit on connection. But I don't want to in each method since there are lot of methods which uses this connection. And the autocommit is set to false on connection.

Is there any listener available in Java through which Connection Pool events like borrowed connection put back to the pool can be listened and I can add a commit on connection?

Comment: As far i know, connection is returned in `pool` after you close it via `close()` method, generally in a `finally` block, and even a better practice is to have a method which close all the resources. Can't you call `commit()` in this method before closing the connection?

Comment: Yes, this is the ideal approach. Since I have already written lot of methods I don't want to change all these methods. I was thinking of an approach where I could do this at one place to save time.